# D3 , NVD3 Line chart hide options

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Im using D3 , NVD3 charts and I want to hide , or even better , i would like to be able to move options for line chart to the left on small examples like this

[image: As you can see "Expanded is not visible nice"]

can I maybe change font size here or anything else I mentioned above ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on `i would like to be able to move options for line chart to the left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no option for this in NVD3, but you can modify the chart manually like this to achieve what you want:

```
d3.select(".nv-legend > g").attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `nvd3.css` to change the font :

```
svg text {
    font: normal 12px sans-serif;
}
```

Use Firebug or the Chrome Element inspector to check the styles applied in the css.

Hope it helps.